# How to send message from client to server using Apache Thrift

Tags: c#, multithreading, thrift

I am creating an application using Apache Thrift technology http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/. I knew how to create a connection between client and server and I can call a function stored in server by client. 
But now, I want to send a message from client to server like "Hello from client", and the server have to recieve and print it. I can do it by using the .NET framework and multi-threading waiting for message. But I would to use the Apache Thrift Technology because of my lecturer's offer.
After server recieved this message, it can reply it to client something like "I got it", and client side will get this message. 
So how can I do that by using Apache Thrift, please give me some advices or some reference materials on it. I would like to use C# to create my application.  
Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) What did you try? (2) What speakes against `Console.WriteLine(yourstring)`? (3) I can't see the relation between printing a value and the RPC technology used to transmit that value. Could you help? (4) The caption of the question is not related to the content.

Comment: I would like to use Apache Thrift for sending data from client to server. The data maybe a message as I explained. In the server side, I created an recieve message thread that will wait for recieving message from client. But I don't know how to send message from the client side.

Comment: So it is really about establishing a connection, and all occurrences of "I can" above should be read as "I want to"?

Comment: BTW, that wiki link is outdated. Use http://thrift.apache.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not post any code, I can only give you the generic outline.

There are two resources worth looking at when starting with Apache Thrift. First, there is the [tutorial](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/csharp), which is about a small calculator app demonstrating the basic principles. Theoretically, this should already cover all you need for your task.

But wait, there's more: The other resource is the [Thrift Test Client/Server program](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/lib/csharp/test/ThriftTest), which besides its primary purpose also gives a good sample and showing a number of techniques regarding the different protocols and transports.

The creation of a client with C# boils down to this:

```
// put together a protocol/transport stack as required by the server
TTransport transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9090);
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
Calculator.Client client = new Calculator.Client(protocol);

// make sure the transport is open
transport.Open();

// call a method via RPC
client.ping();
```

Again, I encourage you to make your question more specific, if you have a concrete problem. [The above sample code can be easily found in the docs](http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=tutorial/csharp/CsharpClient/CsharpClient.cs;hb=HEAD) via Google <sup>1)</sup>, so I bet that is either not the real problem or you may be just looking for someone doing your homework for you.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Just look for "thrift tutorial" and click the very first entry in the search results.